# Sending select parameters outside of a function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'am trying to send two select paramaters to a function from outside. What i am trying to achieve is simplified at below

I have a model like this,

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

SampleData:
3 / Barrack / Obama
4 / Vladimir / Putin
```

and an another model

```
public class IdTextModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to create a function like this

```
public List<IdNameModel> GetList(propselectorA, propselectorB){
    return data.Select(x => new IdTextModel(){
        Id = propselectorA,
        Text = propselectorB
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = GetList(x => x.Id, x => x.Surname);

ExpectedResult:
3 / Obama
4 / Putin
```

How can i accomplish that? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the type you're looking for is `Expression<Func<Entity, string>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Expression<Func<Entity,IdNameModel>>` to abstract out the types of `Id` and `Text`:

```
public List<T> GetList(
    Expression<Func<Entity,T>> selector
) {
    return data.Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var list = GetList(x => IdTextModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Surname } );
```

Passing selectors for two string properties is also possible, but using `Zip` makes it less efficient:

```
public List<IdTextModel> GetList(
    Expression<Func<Entity,string>> selectorId
,   Expression<Func<Entity,string>> selectorName
) {
    return data
       .Select(selectorId)
       .Zip(
           data.Select(selectorName)
       ,   (id, name) => new IdTextModel { Id = id, Name = name }
       ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.        public List<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<Entity,T>> selector
        )  
        {
            var data = new List<Entity>();
            return data.Select(selector);
        }

Comment: @ilkerunal `data` should not be a new list. I assume that you have data context available, so it should be something like `dataContext.EntityTable.Select(selector).ToList();`